# Request and response between JAX-RS and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, jax-rs

Hi I have a simple Rest service:

```
    @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Product createProduct(Product product) {
    if (!(productDao.findByName(product.getProductName()).isEmpty())) {
                //?????
    } else {
        productDao.create(product);
                //?????
    }
    return product;
}
```

When input name is incorrect and method findByName return not null I want return from my rest service method to angular only information, example "Product exist". When method findByName return null and product is created I want return Product from my method to Angular controller. How handle it? Return entity and information?

And what I handle it in my angular controller? Below controller wokrs good when I return entity, but I don't now why handle information "Product exist" not entity?

```
            $scope.addProduct = function (product) {
            $http.post(serviceURI + "products", product).success(function (data) {
                $scope.products.push(data);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                $scope.message = "Product added";
            }).error(function (error) {
                $('.error-message').fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                $scope.message = "Error";
            });
        }
```

How is the best practice to return data and information from JAX-RS and get it in Angular controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I use JAX-RS for the input and Gson for the output when the response is ok because I need to manipulate dates (long/Calendar) and with Gson is easy to add adapters. When the response is not ok, I return a status error code.

```
 @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Product createProduct(Product product) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        //.registerTypeAdapter(Calendar.class, new CalendarSerializer())
        //          .registerTypeAdapter(Calendar.class, new CalendarDeserializer())
        //          .registerTypeAdapter(GregorianCalendar.class,
        //                  new CalendarSerializer())
                            .create();

        String json = null;

        //do something

        json = gson.toJson(product);
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();


        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            return Response.serverError().status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            return Response.serverError().status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        finally{
    }
}
```

Client with AngularJs:

```
.success (function(data) {
        //ok -> get data

})
.error (function(resp) {
    if (resp.errorCode == 400){
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since RESTFul webservices work with the HTTP vocabulary I suggest to return different HTTP status codes depending on the outcome of your operations.

In the first case you could throw a [WebApplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) with a status code of the 4xx family.

In the second case you could use the default status code (I think it would be 200 in this case) or provide a more specific status code such as 201 (Created) by returning a [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object instead of a Product directly.
Eg. [Response.created](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created-java.net.URI-) might help you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html